# Adding SKU information to Shopping Cart in Magento

Tags: php, magento, cart

My client needs to have the sku number, next to the Product Name in the Magento Shopping Cart.  I tried adding this code:

```
<?php echo $this->__('Style Number : %s', $_product->getSku()) ?>
```

but I get this message:

"Fatal error: Call to a member function getSku() on a non-object."

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: what template are you editing?

Answer (score 6):

If you edit `DOCROOT\app\design\frontend\default\themename\template\checkout\cart\item\default.phtml` and add

```
<?php echo $_item->getSku() ?>
```

That should work.

JD

Comment: Thank you very much.  It worked like a dream.  Funny, the code I initially used worked on Product pages, but it would not work on the shopping cart.  If you don't mind, can you point me to the reason behind it?  Thank you very much.  Now I just need to figure out how to sign up so that I can give you some points for the answer.

Comment: On the product pages, the variable that holds the product information is called `$_product` - on the cart page, it's called `$_item`.  Have a look at line 27 (`<?php $_item = $this->getItem()?>`) in the file you just edited to see where the variable is created.

Comment: P.S. If it worked for you, please either upvote or accept the answer with the tick, that's how Stack Overflow works :)  Great to see you here :)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.woolleydesign.net/2011/05/magento-adding-short-description-to-the-shopping-cart/

Got some assistance from here as well, great post for any others interested

Answer (score 0):

Works perfect - only one piece of advice for some uncertain where to drop this code.

I added it after line 37 in default.phtml after the  closure

Reason being is in the wrong place it won't show up under the product name if I add it after line 27.

My lines 37-39 on Magento 1.5 for default.phtml mentioned above

```
</h2>
    <?php echo $_item->getSku() ?>
<?php if ($_options = $this->getOptionList()):?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
<?php echo $_item->getSku() ?>
```

inserted in:

```
app\design\frontend\default\themename\template\checkout\cart\item\default.phtml
```

exactley above line:

```
<?php if ($_options = $this->getOptionList()):?>
```

as per the above Mike answer solved for me one of the main problems.
Is working well also with SCP installed. 
I got, in the cart, the SKU of the selected simple object associated to a configurable product.

I am on Magento 1.6.2.
PERFECT.

Thanks Jonathan, thanks Mike, thanks to all.